# Расстановка знаков с названиями

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли расставлены знаки в предложении:

*Его детство прошло под лозунгами: "Долой буржуев!", "Слава КПСС!".*

Нужно ли двоеточие, нужна ли точка в конце перед следующим предложением и нужна ли запятая после названия первого лозунга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Его детство прошло под лозунгами (какими?) "Долой буржуев!", "Слава КПСС!".

Цитаты составляют ряд несогласованных определений, поэтому **двоеточие можно не ставить, в конце надо поставить точку.**

По Розенталю, точка не требуется при оформлении цитаты  в виде **самостоятельного предложения**, как при прямой речи, но здесь не тот случай.

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие - факультативно (я бы пережила его отсутствие, да пусть себе живёт - примус починяет).

Точка в конце нужна: предложение повествовательное. Вот было бы: "Да чёрт бы побрал эти лозунги - "Долой буржуев!", "Слава КПСС!",

ничего не ставим: интонация последнего лозунга и всего предложения восклицательная.

А как же ж жить без запятой меж двумями лозунгами?! Ну и что, что там внутри кавычек понаставлено?! (А понаставлен один скромный восклицательный знак...)